# Enterprise library logging : how to print method name and line number with each log entry.

Tags: enterprise-library

Is there a predifined way of doing this or do we need to define our own custom formatter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the method name by configuring your TextFormatter in the config file.  I've included the whole formatter to give you some context but the key thing to look for is the **{property(MethodName)}** in the template attribute.  I'm not sure how to get the line number.

```
<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <formatters>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Title: {title}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}&#xA;Type: {property(TypeName)}{newline}&#xA;Method: {property(MethodName)}{newline}&#xA;Parameters: {dictionary({key} : {value};)}{newline}&#xA;Return Value: {property(ReturnValue)}{newline}&#xA;Call Time: {property(CallTime)}{newline}" 
        name="Detailed Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
</loggingConfiguration>
```

The MSDN article on [Configuring Formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664562%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) mentions these special tokens but unfortunately doesn't explain how to use them very well.

Comment: This is wrong, and does not work. the `{property()}` formatter is used for printing object properties of the underlying LogEntry object such as `ActivityId`

Answer (score 3):

You dont say which version of EntLib you are using but given the date of your post I will assume EntLib 5.0.

The part of the format string you would be interested in is:

```
Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}
```

This is a part of the total "default" formatter template found in your config file as below:

```
    <formatters>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}" name="Text Formatter" />
  </formatters>
```

So you can see Extended Properties is a dictionary which will be automatically iterated by the Logger when creating the log entry. It's purpose it to provide a quick and dirty way to dump extra output your app may provide. A more complete way to this would be to write a custom formatter that specifically has tokens for each of the objects you would have otherwise added to Extended Properties.

To get properties into this collection just use the appropriate overload of the

```
LogWriter.Write(..)
```

method when making an entry. A few of them have an

```
IDictionary(key, string) properties
```

parameter that you can use to supply these values.

As for line number and method name these can just be inserted into the Dictionary you provide above. To get their values you can just:

```
   private void FillExtraLogInfo(IDictionary<string, object> info)
    {
        StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame(1, true);
        info.Add("Method Name", stackFrame.GetMethod().ToString());
        info.Add("Line Number" stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber());
    }
```

Comment: Worth saying that getting the StackFrame is a very expensive operation and the stack trace is likely to be incorrect if using a release build with optimisations enabled where methods have been inlined by the JIT compiler.

Comment: Nice. Note `stackFrame.ToString()` will provide filename, method name, and line number in a single string.